# How to set a different background-color to a disabled button with QSS?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qt5.3

I have already tried to use `disabled` and `!enabled` but it doesn't work.
Here is my QSS code :

```
QPushButton {
    background-color:#44c767;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-right:10px;
    outline: 0;
}

QPushButton:hover:!pressed {
    background-color:#54d777;
}

QPushButton: pressed {
    background-color:#30b252;
}

QPushButton: disabled {
    background-color:#ff0000;
}

QPushButton: !enabled {
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

The documentation refers to a [`disabled`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#disabled-ps) pseudo state but without providing more information about it.

**Edit**

I am using QT5.3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove all spaces after colons (really ALL - because it invalidates the further css text) and it will work:

```
QPushButton:disabled {
background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Actually, both `disabled` and `!enabled` works.

Comment: Many thanks! This is so stupid! The worst thing is that the little help box on the bottom of the style sheet editor told me that the QSS code was valid ...