# How to make a QCombobox only display content (not editable, not selectable)

Tags: qt, combobox, readonly

I have a problem with `QComboBox` like this: I have a `QComboBox` for configuring color, I use `QColorDialog` in `QComboBox`. In display mode, I just want to display value of `QComboBox` for user, user cannot edit value or select other value from `QComboBox`. I tried 2 solutions like this:

- use set property `editable = false`: user still chooses other value by selecting combobox
- use set property `enable = false`: user cannot edit or select, but color in combobox is grey, not value that I configured, ex: red.

I googled but don't grab any answers. Somebody helps me?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do you mean by `QColorDialog` in `QComboBox`? You may want to specify the [color when disabled using qss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139616/how-to-set-a-different-background-color-to-a-disabled-button-with-qss).

Comment: Could you clarify with an screenshot how it looks? Is the QColorDialog an option in your QComboBox, next to other items?

Answer (score 1):

You could disallow changes by creating a slot for currentIndexChanged:

[image]

and changing it back.